# Import JQuery UI with ES6 / JSPM

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, ecmascript-6, jspm

I have a Backbone application written in TypeScript, and I'm trying to port it to JSPM modular loading. I have a base class like so:

```
import * as Backbone from "backbone";
import Marionette from "backbone.marionette";
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

export class BaseDocumentView extends Marionette.LayoutView<BaseDocumentModel> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.$el = bootstrap(this.el);
    }
}
```

That line:

```
this.$el = bootstrap(this.el);
```

Is to "enhance" the Backbone $el object with Bootstrap goodness e.g. this.$(viewElement).popover().

The complication is I have a class that inherits from BaseDocumentView. Let's call it SpecialDocumentView. It needs to use a jQuery UI plugin:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import jqueryui from 'jquery-ui';

export class SpecialDocumentView extends BaseDocumentView {

constructor(){
    super();
    // What's do be done here?
}
```

I've got a $, I've got a backbone this.$el with the bootstrap modifications - now I need to extend it again with jQuery UI functionality.

EDIT: I'd like to expand on this a little, as I'm looking for a general insight. In my application I could have different types of jQuery extensions:

- Bootstrap
- JQuery UI
- Another 3rd party thing
- A custom plugin, that extends $.fn

In the old world, all of these simply added to the $ on the window. It's far less clear to me how to consistently approach importing plugins in an ES6 class. (And not to mention the added problem of the Backbone $el I'm trying to keep up to date). Looking for how to have a dollar I can trust!